# Handle User Control exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, user-controls

I have an application with several User Controls. I want to handle unexpected errors of User Controls so that when an User Control crashes, I remove it and add to my form to prevent crash of main application.

In User Control, I used these events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ErrFunc);
Applicaiton.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ErrFunc2);
```

When User Control crashes, I trigger an event to the main form which in it; I try to remove the User Control and add a new one:

```
this.Controls.Remove(crashedUserControl);
crashedUserControl = null;
crashedUserControl = new CameraControl();
this.Controls.Add(crashedUserControl);
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I remove crashed User Control from my form and add dynamically a new one to my form?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work.  Contact the owner or vendor of the control for support.

Comment: May be better solution is to reload the form

Comment: I own the User Control. I want to remove the User Control when crashes and add new one. Is it not possible?